# How to send command output to GNU Screen's copy mode buffer

Tags: gnu-screen, copy-paste

Is there a way to send the output of a command to a GNU Screen's copy mode buffer. I'd like to type something like this:

```
$ echo 'this is an example' | screen_send_to_copy_mode
```

or, maybe

<kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>Some key</kbd>

and then, after that, when I pressed <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd> I would get `this is an example` as an output. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
screen_send_to_copy_mode() (
  tmp=$(mktemp) || exit
  cat > "$tmp" &&
    screen -X readbuf "$tmp"
  ret=$?
  (sleep 2; rm -f -- "$tmp")&
  exit "$ret"
)

echo 'this is an example' | screen_send_to_copy_mode
```

Answer (score 1):

You could redirect the output of the commands to the screen *exchange-file*.

As the ubication of this file is distribution dependent you should first assign your own file,

<kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> bufferfile *your-file*

Redirect the output of the commands to *your-file* and then to update the paste buffer and paste it,

<kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd><kbd><</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>

To restore the screen's default *exchange-file*,

<kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> bufferfile